# Laravel is not connecting to database on Docker/ docker-compose on Windows

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am working on a Laravel project using Docker. The following is my `docker-compose.yml` file that I use for the development environment.

```
 version: '3'
  services:
    apache:
      container_name: pathien_apache
      image: webdevops/apache:ubuntu-16.04
      environment:
        WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
        WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN: pathien.localhost
        WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
      volumes: # Only shared dirs to apache (to be served)
        - ./public:/var/www/public:cached
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:cached
      networks:
        - pathien-network
      ports:
        - "8081:80"
        - "443:443"
    php-fpm:
      container_name: pathien_php
      image: jguyomard/laravel-php:7.3
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/
        - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
        - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
        - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
        - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
        - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.json
        - ./composer.json:/var/www/composer.lock
        - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      links:
        - es01
      networks:
        - pathien-network
    db:
      container_name: pathien_db
      image: mariadb:10.2
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: pathien
        MYSQL_USER: pathien
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      volumes:
        - pathien-data:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
        - pathien-network
      ports:
        - "33060:3306"
    es01:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
      container_name: es01
      environment:
        - node.name=es01
        - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
        - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      volumes:
        - es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - 9200:9200
      networks:
        - pathien-network
    kibana:
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.1
      container_name: pathien_kibana
      environment:
        - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
      ports:
        - "5601:5601"
      networks:
        - pathien-network
  networks:
    pathien-network:
      driver: "bridge"
  volumes:
    pathien-data:
      driver: "local"
    es-data:
      driver: "local"
```

As you can see, I have a database image with the container name `pathein_db`. I am trying to connect it from the Laravel application setting the credentials in the `.env` file as follows.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pathein
DB_USERNAME=pathein
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then I tried running the migration command

```
$ docker-compose exec php-fpm php artisan migrate
```

but got the following error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pathein'@'172.21.0.6' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pathein'@'172.21.0.6' (using password: YES)")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=pathein", "pathein", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

This means that it is literally failing to connect to the database.

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try using the container name on `DB_HOST` variable in the .env file, `DB_HOST=pathien_db`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelled pathien wrong.

in your `docker-compose.yml` you have:-

```
MYSQL_DATABASE: pathien
MYSQL_USER: pathien
```

in your `.env` you have:

```
DB_DATABASE=pathein
DB_USERNAME=pathein
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.